# How to use the android Geocoder with Mapbox instead of the Mapbox Geocoder?

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, mapbox

AS the title states, my country unfortunately is not yet covered by the Mapbox Geocoder, so until it is I have to make due with the android one. The problem is that I am struggling to get the android geocoder to work in place of the Mapbox one.

I'm trying to get the Camera Mapbox example to move the camera to the address I put into the editText box.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            // When user clicks the map, animate to new camera location
            EditText etAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
            String location = etAddress1.getText().toString();

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
            List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

            if (list.size() > 0) {

                Address add = list.get(0);
                String locality = add.getLocality();
                Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                end = Position.fromCoordinates(add.getLongitude(), add.getLatitude());

                GoBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void OnClick(View v) {
                    CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(end.getLatitude(), end.getLongitude()) // Sets the new camera position
                            .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                            .bearing(180) // Rotate the camera
                            .tilt(30) // Set the camera tilt
                            .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

                    mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(position), 7000);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

public void geoLocate (View v) throws IOException {
    hideSoftKeyboard(v);

    EditText etAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddress);
    String location = etAddress1.getText().toString();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 2);

    if (list.size() > 0) {

        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)) // Sets the new camera position
                .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(180) // Rotate the camera
                .tilt(30) // Set the camera tilt
                .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder

        mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(position), 7000);

    }
}

private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Here is my .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Set the starting camera position and map style using xml-->
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    mapbox:style_url="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
    mapbox:center_latitude="40.73581"
    mapbox:center_longitude="-73.99155"
    mapbox:zoom="11"
    mapbox:access_token="my access token"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAddress"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:hint="Search Location"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="12dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:text="Go"
    android:onClick="geoLocate"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mapView" />
```

Comment: Hey could you clarify on whether you are using the Google Android geocoder or [MAS geocoder](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#geocoder)?

Comment: I am using the standard Google Android Geocoder, unfortunately the Mapbox Geocoder does not work in South Africa.

Comment: I still have not been able to figure the Geocoder out, have you got any suggestion as to how I could approach it? :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Mapbox Geocoder works for South Africa.  I was successful in Geocoding this address.  Here is the [result](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e2cf609481b22b6edff397073c2147b), using the [Mapbox Command Line Interface](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-cli-py).

```
mapbox geocoding 'Pretoria'
```

This is a great tool to verify if the Mapbox services do what you need it to do.

---

Now, back to your Android problem.  If the Mapbox Geocoding works for your particular place in South Africa, then you can see this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/geocoding/) on how to use Geocoding using Mapbox Android Services.  (also posted by @cammace)